# Can Ansible Push SSH Pub key Even If the User's Home DIR Hasn't Been Created?

Tags: ansible, ssh-keys

Servers are connected to the AD environment. I want to push the pub key to enable passwordless access.

However, I found my playbook failed if the user's home directory was not present. Do I have to create a separate task to create the user's home dir before kicking off the key-pushing job?

Here is my playbook:

```
---
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  tasks:
  - name: Set authorized key from file
    authorized_key:
      user: user1
      state: present
      manage_dir: yes
      key: "{{ lookup('file', item) }}"
    with_fileglob:
    - user1.pubkey
```

Comment: You could specify the `path` parameter if you want the key to be copied to a different location. However in an ideal situation, the user (and home directory) creation  should be managed by Ansible as well, so that this discrepancy will not arise.

Comment: If that's the case, the authorized_key module won't be beneficial. I tried the ```path``` parameter, and it also requires a current path to copy. So I will have to tell Ansible the ownership for creating the home dirs which can be complex if different users belong to various groups.